# Tikz-dependency and gb4e Alignment Issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, gb4e

I am using tikz-dependency and gb4e inside one example. I want them to be centered, but I could not managed to do so. Here's my self advancement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\exewidth{(\thexnumi)}
\noautomath

\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd,/depgraph/.search also = {/tikz},
baseline=-0.6ex, inner sep=-0.1cm, edge horizontal padding=3pt, edge unit distance=1.8ex}

\title{stackoverflow}
\author{Utku Turk}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\begin{exe}
\centering
    \ex
        \scalebox{1.1}{
        \begin{dependency}
            \begin{deptext}[column sep=.3cm]
            This \& is \& a \& sentence \\
        \end{deptext}
            \deproot{4}{\textsc{root}}
            \depedge{2}{1}{\textsc{syn2}}
            \depedge[edge style={ultra thick}]{4}{2}{\textsc{\textbf{syn1}}}
            \depedge[edge unit distance=3ex,edge style={densely dotted}]{4}{2}{\textsc{syn3}}
            \depedge{4}{3}{\textsc{syn4}}
            \wordgroup{1}{1}{2}{syn5}
        \end{dependency}
        }
    \gll  This is a sentence.  \\
     this is a gloss  \\
    \glt ``Translation of what is what"
    \label{ex:sentence}
\end{exe}
\caption{vvvvvvvvv. }
\label{secondexample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried with figure centering, inside exe centering, I also tried \hfill and \hfill \null around the sentences. None of them worked. Thank you for your help.

Right now, I found a way to circumvent this from happening. I added `\hspace{110pt}` before the example. And changed the value according to the length of the sentence.

But I still appreciate a better way to do so.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Rather than posting a code snippet you should give a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that can be compiled.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to do that however, I am working on a specific submission for a specific conference, I did not want to reveal my identity and I did not know how to provide their style with a standalone tex file. I will read your link and try to provide that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you again, now I understand what you meant and I have provided a minimal working example.

Comment: `gb4e` examples are not  really designed to be centred.  Do you really want to put it inside a `figure` environment (also not what it was designed for) or was that just an attempt to centre it?

Comment: @AlanMunn I do not really care about putting inside a Figure. That was my bad attempt. I want them immediately under the tikz dependency tree and centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the example and the number centred, or just the content with the example number left aligned as usual, but you can centre the whole example using the `varwidth` package, which creates minipages to the natural width of their contents.  Here's a version which centres just the content and leaves the number aligned at the left. We do this by wrapping the `varwidth` environment between two `\hfil` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\exewidth{(\thexnumi)}
\noautomath

\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd,/depgraph/.search also = {/tikz},
baseline=-0.6ex, inner sep=-0.1cm, edge horizontal padding=3pt, edge unit distance=1.8ex}

\title{stackoverflow}
\author{Utku Turk}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{exe}
    \ex\hfil
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
        \scalebox{1.1}{
        \begin{dependency}
            \begin{deptext}[column sep=.3cm]
            This \& is \& a \& sentence \\
        \end{deptext}
            \deproot{4}{\textsc{root}}
            \depedge{2}{1}{\textsc{syn2}}
            \depedge[edge style={ultra thick}]{4}{2}{\textsc{\textbf{syn1}}}
            \depedge[edge unit distance=3ex,edge style={densely dotted}]{4}{2}{\textsc{syn3}}
            \depedge{4}{3}{\textsc{syn4}}
            \wordgroup{1}{1}{2}{syn5}
        \end{dependency}
        }
    \gll  This is a sentence.  \\
     this is a gloss  \\
    \glt ``Translation of what is what"
    \label{ex:sentence}
    \end{varwidth}\hfil
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Alternatively, if you want both the content and the example number centred you can just use `varwidth` inside a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\exewidth{(\thexnumi)}
\noautomath

\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd,/depgraph/.search also = {/tikz},
baseline=-0.6ex, inner sep=-0.1cm, edge horizontal padding=3pt, edge unit distance=1.8ex}

\title{stackoverflow}
\author{Utku Turk}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
        \scalebox{1.1}{
        \begin{dependency}
            \begin{deptext}[column sep=.3cm]
            This \& is \& a \& sentence \\
        \end{deptext}
            \deproot{4}{\textsc{root}}
            \depedge{2}{1}{\textsc{syn2}}
            \depedge[edge style={ultra thick}]{4}{2}{\textsc{\textbf{syn1}}}
            \depedge[edge unit distance=3ex,edge style={densely dotted}]{4}{2}{\textsc{syn3}}
            \depedge{4}{3}{\textsc{syn4}}
            \wordgroup{1}{1}{2}{syn5}
        \end{dependency}
        }
    \gll  This is a sentence.  \\
     this is a gloss  \\
    \glt ``Translation of what is what"
    \label{ex:sentence}
\end{exe}
\end{varwidth}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you! The first solution was exactly what I was looking for.